# Is it possible to retrieve the time for a route with the iOS Google Maps SDK?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-geocoding-api, google-directions-api

Using the Google Maps SDK for iOS, is it possible to calculate/retrieve the time for a route from location A to location B that is taken by bike, by car or or walking as it is done in the regular Google Maps app for iOS?

I know that directions can be displayed using a GMSPolyLine using the Google Directions API, now is it possible to calculate the time need to walk all the way along the polyline from A to B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directions API includes a duration in the legs in the response:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Legs

These durations will depend on the travel mode (driving, walking, etc) that you specified in the request:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes